# With FFmpeg yuv encoded into H264 and encapsulated into ts, ts video found the length of time shorter?

Tags: ffmpeg

With FFmpeg the mov directly into yuv, then yuv encoded into H264 and encapsulated into ts, ts video found less than the length of time the length of the mov video time. I want to know how to modify the FFmpeg command to solve the video time length shorter problem

The `ffmpeg` command is as follows：

```
ffmpeg-i 00.mov 01.yuv
ffmpeg-s 1920x800-pix_fmt yuv420p-i 01.yuv-vcodec libx264-x264-params fps=24 02.h264.
ffmpeg-i 02.h264 03.ts
```

Use `ffprobe` to view the 00.mov details are as follows：

```
Duration: 00: 12: 14.17, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6361 kb/s
     Stream #0:0 (eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x800 [SAR 1: 1 DAR 12: 5], 6162 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24 tbn, 48 tbc (default)
     Metadata:
       handler_name: VideoHandler
       encoder: libx264
     Stream # 0:1 (eng): Audio: mp3 (. mp3 / 0x33706D2E), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 191 kb/s (default)
     Metadata:
       handler_name: SoundHandler
```

Use `ffprobe` to view the 03.ts details are as follows：

```
Duration: 00:11:44.80, start: 1.440000, bitrate: 2242 kb/s
   Program 1 
     Metadata:
       service_name: Service01
       service_provider: FFmpeg
     Stream #0:0 [0x100]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p (tv, progressive), 1920x800 [SAR 1:1 DAR 12: 5], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
```

How to modify the `ffmpeg` command to make the ts video duration equal to the duration of the mov video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the 2nd command, add -framerate 24 for the input. The x264 fps signaling only affects ratecontrol and not any framerate metadata in the raw .264 output.

Also, add -c copy in the 3rd comand to avoid re-encoding.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help